# Fullcalendar - How to Immediately put ID (from db) into Event?

Tags: jquery, resources, resize, fullcalendar, move

Got Fullcalendar (resource fork) with MySQL working well, inserting.

And then moving & resizing events... but only after a page reload.

I can't find the way to immediately add the db ID to the event.  The result is, when a user makes an event and then immediately moves (or resizes) it, I can't update the db.

I have the mysql_insert_id returning, and seem to have tried everything I know to get it available where its needed, wherever that might be...

```
if (title) {
                $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "db_actions.php",
                          data: { 
                            equipment_id: resource.id,
                            start: start, 
                            end: end,
                            title: title,
                      }
                    })

                    .done(function( id ) {
                        alert( "Resulting mysql_insert_id is " + id);
                      });

                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        resource: resource.id,
                        event_id:id
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
```

Any thoughts?  Much appreciated.

Mark

=============================================

Update...

Ah hah!

One easy answer...  move the render up inside the callback, allowing access to the id variable.

```
if (title) {
            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "db_actions.php",
                      data: { 
                        equipment_id: resource.id,
                        start: start, 
                        end: end,
                        title: title,
                  }
                })

                .done(function( id ) {

                    alert( "Resulting mysql_insert_id is " + id);

                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                       title: title,
                       start: start,
                       end: end,
                       allDay: allDay,
                       resource: resource.id,
                      event_id:id
                   },
                  true // make the event "stick"
                   );

          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the database_id as custom property to your fullcalendar event object. This property is then available in any fullcalendar method like "eventClick",

I usually do this in a "fillCalendar" method which receives the result of an AJAX-Call.

```
fillCalendar(dbObjects) {
   fcEvents = [];
   ...
   fcEvents.push( {
      database_id: dbObjects[i].id,
                   title: title,
                   start: start,
                   end: end,
                   allDay: allDay,
                   resource: resource.id,
                   event_id:id
   }
   ...
   return fcEvents;

}
```